# Selenium with Microsoft Edge driver never finishes initialising

Tags: selenium

I'm using the C# bindings for Selenium and trying to get a simple automated test in Microsoft Edge working.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
        options.PageLoadStrategy = EdgePageLoadStrategy.Eager;
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://bing.com/";
    }
}
```

But the program halts on the initialisation of the `EdgeDriver`, the edge browser launches but the url never changes to "bing.com".

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Do you have any references to your edgedriver.exe?  Not specifying where to find it could result in this behavior.

Comment: I've tried running it with the path passed in to the EdgeDriver constructor as an argument and it does the same thing as the code above :/

Comment: What version of Selenium WebDriver are you running? Can you confirm that you are running this on a reasonably updated Windows 10 installation? Try inserting this statement before driver.url *driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));*

Comment: Hey Mike, I am using the latest versions of the C# bindings and the latest version of the Edge driver. Unfortunately that fails because the initialise function never actually returns a result.

Comment: Any error in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Edge starts with a blank page (I had it starting on google)!  In settings, select:-
'Open with' = 'New tab page'
'Open new tabs with' = 'A blank page'

This is a workaround as OP points out, and I too think there is a defect within the Microsoft Webdriver2; but it works for me.